# Struts 2 action error messages

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am having a jsp page with two forms pointed to two action classes respectively. Now each form has a field where i have displayed the action errors & messages as :

```
<s:actionerror/>
<s:actionmessage/>
```

Now the problem is that, when action error/message is reported for any of the form ..the error/message is displayed in the both fields of the forms.

**How do i specify an action error message respective to action class.**

Answer (score 2):

Return the same parameter with different values from both Actions to know which Action you are coming from, and show `<actionerror/>` and `<actionmessage/>` only inside its form.

```
<s:form action="firstAction">
    <s:if test="form==1">
        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:actionmessage/>
    </s:if>       
    <s:textfield name="someData" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>


<s:form action="secondAction">
    <s:if test="form==2">
        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:actionmessage/>
    </s:if>    
    <s:textfield name="someOtherData" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

In firstAction.java

```
@Getter         private final static int form = 1;
@Getter @Setter private String someData;
```

In secondAction.java:

```
@Getter         private final static int form = 2;
@Getter @Setter private String someOtherData;
```

Comment: what are these new annotations ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using `addActionError` or `addActionMessage` methods. But you can use `addFieldError` method with such key that it is not a name of any of the fields in your actions. And in JSP use `<s:fielderror>` tag to display that message.

Somewhere in the action class:

```
addFieldError("your_action_name_", "your_message");
```

Somewhere in other action class:

```
addFieldError("your_other_action_name_", "your_other_message");
```

In JSP:

```
<s:fielderror fieldName="your_action_name_" />

<s:fielderror fieldName="your_other_action_name_" />
```

Comment: I believed this will not server purpose for OP, in some cases its quite possible that we need to show error at action level and not field level.Seems like its a good option to have a attribute in `<s:actionerror/>` to bind it to specific action ;)

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: Maybe it is a good feature to have in future. But currently ActionErrors is a list. And using FieldErrors you can do that what OP wants, different messages based on some logic.